# C++11: properly expand template parameter pack in trailing return type

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates, trailing-return-type

I am trying to translate run-time constant to compile-time constant in my C++11 program using `switch` statement. I have `enum SomeEnum {A, B, C};`, and depending on its value I want to call the template function `f<A>()`, `f<B>()` or `f<C>()`. I have lots of template functions in my code that depend on `SomeEnum` (as well as other template parameters), so I decided to make dedicated `dispatch` function. Here is the code I am trying to compile:

```
#include <utility>

enum SomeEnum {
      A, B, C
};

template<template<SomeEnum, typename...> class FUNCTOR, typename ...OTHERS, typename ...ARGS> inline auto dispatch (
    SomeEnum const type,
    ARGS&&... args
) -> decltype( FUNCTOR<A, OTHERS...>::function(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...) ) { //Problem here
    switch(type) {
        case A:
            return FUNCTOR<A, OTHERS...>::function(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
        case B:
            return FUNCTOR<B, OTHERS...>::function(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
        case C:
            return FUNCTOR<C, OTHERS...>::function(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
        default:
            //Do not call any function if enum value is wrong, just return something:
            return decltype( FUNCTOR<A, OTHERS...>::function(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...) )();
    }
}

template<SomeEnum T> struct TemplateFunctor1 {
    static inline int function(int) { return 0; }
};

template<SomeEnum T, class OTHER> struct TemplateFunctor2 {
    static inline int function(int) { return 0; }
};

int main(void) {
    dispatch<TemplateFunctor1>(B, 0); //Problem here!

    dispatch<TemplateFunctor2, int>(B, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

(I do not need to handle the case when function return type depends on template parameter)

I am getting an error while compiling the line `dispatch<TemplateFunctor1>(B, 0);`, where is only one template parameter required by `TemplateFunctor1`. The error messages are following:

`error: no matching function for call to 'dispatch(SomeEnum, int)'`

`note: candidate: template<template<SomeEnum <anonymous>, class ...> class FUNCTOR, class ... OTHERS, class ... ARGS> decltype (FUNCTOR<(SomeEnum)0u, OTHERS ...>::function((forward<ARGS>)(dispatch::args)...)) dispatch(SomeEnum, ARGS&& ...)`

`note: template argument deduction/substitution failed`

`error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)` in this part of code: `FUNCTOR<A, OTHERS...>` of trailing return type.

So I tried to change `FUNCTOR<A, OTHERS...>` in trailing return type to `FUNCTOR<A>`, then the line `dispatch<TemplateFunctor2, int>(B, 0);` cannot be compiled. It says that I provided wrong number of template parameters (1, should be 2), which is quite an expected error.

What I do not understand here is why the same `decltype()` construction works in `default` switch branch, but does not work in the trailing return type?

I can fix my code by changing the standard to C++14 and by removing trailing return type completely, but then I will not understand what is going on here.

I also tried different compilers (ICC, GCC, Clang), and all of them giving similar error messages, so it cannot be a compiler error here.

Comment: gcc compiles this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is, but this workaround seems to be working:

```
  template <template<SomeEnum, typename...> class FUNCTOR, typename... X>
  struct Wrapper
  {
      using Type = FUNCTOR<A, X...>;
  };

  template<template<SomeEnum, typename...> class FUNCTOR, typename ...OTHERS, typename ...ARGS> 
  inline auto dispatch (
      SomeEnum const type,
      ARGS&&... args
  ) -> decltype( Wrapper<FUNCTOR, OTHERS...>::Type::function(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...) ) { //No problem here
```